# Can't paint texture but fill color works

Tags: texture-painting

Here i created some poor feather and I'm trying to paint surface to give feather some color, but it won't let me  paint texture. I use cycles, so I unwrap object then switch to texture paint and choose diffuse color and click on OK then object become black as that color was choosen to start with but when I change color in palette it won't let me paint just nothing happens but if I choose fill color it will very happily fill it with choosen color.

[image]
[image]

Am I doing something wrong or?

Here is the video, note that I'm clicking or click dragging while using texture paint but I dont have cast keys plugin to show it.

Comment: @MrZak That is problem in second screenshot paint should be able to happen yet I can't paint on my object but if I choose fill brush it paints whole object as it should

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was up to settings texture mask (even tho I don't know what is this for) was set to black color/image, after removing painting works as it should.

Comment: That is because the mask being present blocked the paint because it was looking for the white space in the mask texture to deliver the paint, the black is full mask.

Comment: Clicking the little X next to the texture in that section removed the mask. It went from a black square to a checkerboard pattern. Good spot, Black Cloud!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It turned out I was trying to paint on the wrong side of the plane (the normals were flipped). This is why fill worked but brush didn't.

Flip your normals by selecting the object > Edit Mode > select the Mesh drop down > Normals > Flip

Or turn the object around if it's a plane:)